# Number of spanning trees of graph on picture

Tags: graph-theory, trees

[image]

I have to find number of spanning trees of the given graph. I don't think that matrix theorem for trees is optimal here because I would need to calculate determinant of matrix $9$x$9$. Then, recursive formula for spanning trees is also a lot of work because we have so many edges on cycles here. I would like to know if there is some optimal solution, because here we can see graph $K_5$ that is connected with $K_3$  and two more edges. Because we know number of spanning trees of complete graph is $n^{n-2}$ where $n$ is number of vertices, I thought that we can use some trick including this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think you're right. The number of spanning trees of the given graph is $5^3\cdot3^1=475$.

Comment: OK, and why we ignored three bridge edges?

Comment: Because removing any of them would result in an disconnected graph. But a tree is a connected graph.

Comment: So we can always ignore bridges?

Comment: Not ignore, but cherish. :)

Comment: Just to conclude. Since every spanning tree has $9$ edges in this example, and because we have three bridges, all of them need to be in every spanning tree. So we have 6 edges left for every spanning tree. Since $K_5$ has spanning trees with 4 edges each, and $K_3$ with 2 edges, those are $6$ edges that are left for every tree. Is this correct?

Comment: @Trevor Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a little more theory to kabenyuk's correct answer. Any given graph can be decomposed into its maximal 2-connected components. Replacing each 2-connected component with a single vertex always gives a tree graph (I think there is a name for this but I can't think of it right now). One can then show that a spanning tree of the entire graph always consists of this tree graph plus a spanning tree of each 2-connected component. Hence the number of spanning trees of the entire graph is the product of the number of spanning trees of the 2-connected components. This should be explained in most graph theory text books, I read it in Diestel.

In the example given above the two 2-connected components are a $K_5$ and a $K_3$ with $5^3$ and $3$ spanning trees respectively. So this gives $5^3\times 3$ spanning trees for the entire graph.